# Проблема с Bitmap

Tags: c#, bitmap

```
        {
            var sample = new Bitmap(pathSampleImage);
            var orig = new Bitmap(pathOriginalImage);

            ExhaustiveTemplateMatching tm = new ExhaustiveTemplateMatching(0.90f);
            _matchings = tm.ProcessImage(orig, sample);

            return _matchings[1].Similarity;
        }
```

Битмап не принимает мой путь к картинкам ,после клика на кнопку пишет, что ошибка System.ArgumentException: "Недопустимый параметр.", хотя проверял уже 10 раз , путь верный
ImageProcessing  - класс в котором находится функция IsContaints, [![фото ошибки][1]][1]
Ошибка возникает сразу после нажатия на кнопку

````
        {
            ImageProcessing image = new ImageProcessing();
           richTextBox1.AppendText(image.IsContains("C:/Users/s/Downloads/SOrusExamples-master/SOrusExamples-master/SearchImage/WpfAppUI/Assets/Original.jpg", "C:/Users/s/Downloads/SOrusExamples-master/SOrusExamples - master/SearchImage/WpfAppUI/Assets/Flag.jpg").ToString());
        }
    }```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BxN4l.png
````

Comment: Где у вас выскакивает ошибка? Дайте самодостаточный пример, который воспроизведет у нас эту проблему. Что такое `ImageProcessing` и зачем он здесь?

Comment: Обновил, надеюсь все стало понятнее

Comment: Напишите перед `var sample = new Bitmap(pathSampleImage);` следующее: `Process.Start(pathSampleImage);`, откроется ли фото? Если нет, то вы явно пишете туда неверный путь. Я лично у себя вашу проблему воспроизвести не смог, падало с подобной ошибкой только тогда, когда файл по данному пути был не найден.

Comment: @YSopd, а вот у Вас в пути ко второму файлу есть пробелы, судя по скрину, падает именно на попытке создать Bitmap из него, попробуйте использовать пути без пробелов, спецсимволов, русских букв.